# Replace junk character apostrophe using regex

Tags: java, regex, apostrophe

All the apostrophe in my HTML is being converted to junk by the UI engine. I need to create a regex with below pattern to replace the string in Java.

The specific pattern is needed because the some characters are displayed as junk from the HTML.  The whole string can be like : company㝵20ac?s

```
[2 characters]+"20ac"+[1 character]
```

I need to replace this whole string with a single quote. Something like:

```
string.replaceAll(<regex>, "\'");
```

It should not be like this but the junk characters cannot be parsed by any java or HTML anymore once saved in the database.

Comment: the unicode codepoint associated with `\u20ac` is the EURO SIGN character.  The best you can do is to change it for `EUR` sequence, so you don't have any more problems with euros.  A little more of context or a better description of your problem (better than calling _junk_ the thing) could lead to a better solution.  Probably if the HTML generator uses Java `&#x20ac;` character sequence instead of the `€` character, the browsers can display it properly.  What are the two characters that precede the `20ac` seq?

Answer (score 1):

If you want any 2 characters followed by `20ac` and then another character you can do something like this:

`string.replaceAll("..(20ac).","'$1'");`

The `.` means any character.
What's in the parenthesis will be captured and used later with `$1`.

[Regex explanation](https://regexr.com/43bqh)

If you want to replace only junk characters you need to define them in the regex instead of the `.`.
Can be something like this: `[㝵]` (put all the junk characters inside the brackets).
For multiple characters you can use `*` for zero or more, `+` for one or more and `{2}` for exactly 2 characters.
So the end result can be something like this `[㝵]+(20ac)\?`

[Regex explanation](https://regexr.com/43br3)